# C#, remote screenshot without client and server

Tags: c#, screenshot, remoteview

I just tried a program demonstrated in C# on YouTube. The video shows how to build a client/server based program to capture desktop remotely, and it works perfectly. Now I have a question. Is is possible to do the same job without the client/server architecture? Is there some kind of relative windows API that I can access remotely? My imagination is just to click a button on computer A(with specific program) and receive a screenshot from computer B(without specific program) through network. Is is possible? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, that when you access "some API" remotely and get result from that "some API" it's called a client / server architecture, where you is a client and "some API" is a server.

You can't receive something if there is no one to give))

If you wanted to ask "is there anything in windows that would give me a screenshot without injecting anything and etc?" - then:

1. if you don't care about laws, theoretically, you could find some bug in system itself or applications that are running on it, and through them get access to that computer and make it do whatever you want, that's called hacking, the very black hacking, and that type of things are hard to do.
2. if you care just a little about any of laws and don't want to visit a prison, then the answer is no.

Comment: Well, you could piggy-back on something like Remote Assistance. I wouldn't, though :D

Comment: @Luaan, maybe, if the system is so vulnerable, but not with legitimate usage anyway, even if I make a shot of the display of someone's device, who didn't authorise me to do so, I'm breaching the human rights))

Comment: Thank you for your reply! And Sorry... , I don't know the mechanism of windows and computer much. So maybe I should change the question. Is there any existing windows service that I can access to have a screenshot through network? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @ohnotme, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: @ohnotme, for security reasons, of course not.

Comment: I really didn't notice it's a serious problem, just think maybe a way to see or collect data from many computer(about a hundred) without specific program installed. Now i know it's not possible and illegal. Thank you!

Comment: @ohnotme, yes, that's correct, you're welcome!